# R sum i matrices in a loop

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sum

I calculate 50 matrices in a for loop using **R**. How can i sum up all the `50 matrices` like:

```
for(j in 1:50){

  mat = matrix(j,3,3)

}
```

Its not necessary to keep all 50 matrices. I just need the sum for all calculated matrices in the loop, like 1 + 2 + ... + 49 + 50. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is very unclear what you are trying to do. The code you have posted is obviously not runnable. `for(j in 1:j)` doesn't make any sense if `j` is not defined. Where is `matB_(j-1)` defined? Do you plan to keep each of the `j` matrices or just the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're aiming at:

```
### reproducible
set.seed(1)
### no. matrices
j <- 3
### 'pre-allocate' list
l1 <-  vector("list", length=j)
### fill it (all different)
for (i in 1:j){
    l1[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3)
}
### taken from ?Reduce
add <- function(x) Reduce("+", x)
add(l1)
```

See [`?Reduce`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Reduce) for more examples.

Note semicolon `;` not necessary for line-endings in `R`.

Answer (score 0):

if `matrixlist` is your list with all 50 matrices, wouldn't it be as easy as saying

```
summatrix <- Reduce("+", matrixlist)
```

I just had a similar question and felt that a lot of answers around similar questions are quite complicated. The above code works for me but I'm not sure if it's sufficient. Happy about feedback